# IntegrityError on update_or_create

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an IntegrityError that seems like an impossibility:

```
ShippingAddress.objects.update_or_create(
    subscription=subscription,
    defaults=address_dict,
)
```

(where "subscription" is an instance of a model related via a OneToOneField) raises the error

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '42' for key 'subscription_id'")
```

despite subscription being the only key added to the filter. Even more strangely, neither

```
ShippingAddress.objects.get(
    subscription=subscription,
)
```

nor

```
ShippingAddress.objects.filter(
    subscription=subscription,
)
```

raise the same error. What could be messing up the update() call?

Comment: Please show your model and `address_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

The error turned out to be because the address_dict contained an "id" key that I hadn't noticed when generating it.